# Multiple repositories, single setup

Tags: windows, svn

If I use multiple repositories, all located under a single root folder, how can I set it up so that they will use a single master `svnconf`/`passwd` file for setup but still allow me to customize each if the need arises?

This is on Windows, but I guess the process would be similar on other systems.

**Update:** I am using svnserve as a service.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this type of server configuration type question at http://serverfault.com instead which is just like Stack Overflow except more for server administration.

Comment: In 2008 when I posted this, SO was the only game in town and it is more of a developer question than a SysAdmin question.

Comment: This question is similar another question for which I gave this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530149/access-control-for-multiple-projects-using-svn/3472439#3472439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svnserve` isn't intended for use in large deployments. If you need more fine-grained permissions, or integration, etc., use a web server (like [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using svnserve, then the `conf/svnserve.conf` file in each repository has a configuration item which names the password database file. This is the `password-db` item in the `[general]` section, just set them all to point to the same file.

If you're not using svnserve, then this probably doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing that depending on what exactly you want to achieve and the setup you are using.

**svnserve**

If you use `svnserve`, there is a file in each repository which is called `svnserve.conf` where you can define the password file in use. You could put a password file in the server root and point all your repositories there.

It would look like this:

```
c:\svn\passwd
c:\svn\project1\conf\svnserve.conf
c:\svn\project2\conf\svnserve.conf
```

Then in both `svnserve.conf` files a section like

```
[general]
password-db = c:\svn\passwd
```

should do the trick and will still keep different ACLs (`authz` file) for each repository

**Apache**

That is a bit more complicated but

```
<Location /project1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/Repositories/project1

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Project1 repository"
  AuthUserFile c:/etc/svn-auth-file

  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile c:/etc/svn-acl
</Location>
<Location /project2>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/Repositories/project2

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Project2 repository"
  AuthUserFile c:/etc/svn-auth-file

  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile c:/etc/svn-acl
</Location>
```

As long as you use the same authuserfile for each SVN enabled location, you will get your result.

Comment: Does the password-db work with relative paths? Are Windows style or Unix style paths required or is it whatever the native path syntax is for the system? These are the questions I wish were answered better in the documentation.

Comment: Just an FYI, I've tested using relative Windows style paths and all seems to work as expected. +1 for the answer Jean.